# Spring apply JsonView to an Object after being created?

Tags: java, spring, jackson

Say I've got an object User:

```
@JsonView(User.Activity.class)
String name
@JsonView(User.Activity.class)
int id
String description;
// Realistically there will be a lot more fiels here...
... getters and setters
```

And I've then gone and created one:

```
User u = new User();
u.setName("xoxo");
u.setId(1);
u.setDescription("DESCRIPTION....");
dao.save(u);

return u.withJsonView(User.Activity.class); // Is there a way to apply this?
```

I want to return this object to the client with the fields from a specific `JsonView`. How can I do this?

#### Edit

```
Hashmap hm = new Hashmap();
MappingJacksonValue value = new MappingJacksonValue(user);
value.setSerializationView(User.Activity.class);
hm.put("success", value);

return ResponseEntity.ok(hm); // Returns whole user object :\
```

That is all I'm doing. ***value*** ends up being the whole user object, even though I've only put the `User.activity.class` view on a couple of fields. I'm then simply returning the hashmap in a ***responseentity***

Comment: Yes it is. Another reason why I want to apply a view after creating an object is so I can insert only the data I need into elasticsearch and not the whole object! @CássioMazzochiMolin It'd be amazing if there was something like djangos serialization but for hibernate/jpa objects!

Comment: You are returning a `HashMap` in the `ResponseEntity` instead of return the `MappingJacksonValue` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply a view, use the [`@JsonView`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView.html) annotation on the endpoint method:

```java
@GetMapping
@JsonView(User.Activity.class)
public User getUser() {
    User user = new User();
    return user;
}
```

To apply a view *dynamically*, wrap your POJO into a [`MappingJacksonValue`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJacksonValue.html):

```java
@GetMapping
public MappingJacksonValue getUser(){
    User user = new User();
    MappingJacksonValue value = new MappingJacksonValue(user);
    value.setSerializationView(User.Activity.class);
    return value;
}
```

For more details, check [this post](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring) about Jackson integration in Spring.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work! It just returns the whole object

Comment: I added the neccesary code. The endpoint is simply returning a response entity.

Comment: Ahh silly me. I was thinking that the serialisation occurred at `value.setSerializationView` and that adding the value into the hashmap would have the serialized view!