# Java map object to several variants JSON

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

How can i map domain object to several variant JSON objects (several DTO), without chain DOMAIN_OBJECT->DTO->JSON? I have one big domain object and more than ten variants of representation. When I map domain object to specific DTO with `structMap` and then do serialization to JSON with jackson I spend a lot of time.

Is there any tool for map domain object to serveral variants JSON without midle layer DTO ?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what your *more than ten variants* are like. Sometimes, sticking to DTOs can be the best approach, as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36175349/1426227), where DTOs are used define the contract of REST APIs.

Alternatively, depending on your needs, you could play with [`@JsonView`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView.html) from Jackson. Using Spring? This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39486432/1426227) may give you some insights.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know your use case, but as a note, if you use Jackson I presume you are using `ObjectMapper`. The `ObjectMapper` is an expensive object which you should reuse as much as possible (ergo, declare it `static` and `final`), since it does a lot of caching behind the scene when the same object is converted lot of times.

Even better, get an `ObjectWriter` and/or `ObjectReader` from the `ObjectMapper`, which are immutable and thread-safe (ObjectMapper is tricky if you want to change its configuration at runtime), they should improve your performance.

Final thing, but I never went that far, you could write custom serializer / deserializer, but I see complexity going noticeably up (thus, it will be more difficult to mantain).

If you are working with strings, double check you use the StringBuilder (or StringBuffer on multi-threaded use case) and logging only when necessary (`if(logger.isDebugEnabled() { log.debug(...) }`), they are common pitfalls that bring performances down.

Comment: If the OP is not willing to write DTOs and use [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org), I hardly think custom Jackson serializers and deserializers would be an option for him.